# Is the derivative of a multivalued function defined at its branch point?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I am really sorry if this is a trivial question, but my Complex Analysis TA made me confused regarding this. I'm actually a Physics major so please bear with me.

We know that multivalued functions are non-analytic and the only way to make them analytic is to restrict them to a 'cut-plane'. But my question is about differentiability. For a function such as

$$f(z) = z^{3/2}$$
Is the derivative defined at $z = 0$? The TA said that the derivative is well defined at $z=0$ but I don't think it is because at $z=0$ the function is not even continuous. Can someone please explain this carefully to me, I have a lot of confusion regarding this. Thank you for your help and sorry if I am being naive.

Comment: technically, $f$ is not a function in a neighborhood of $0$, so in that sense it doesn't have a derivative at $0$. OTOH it   has a 2-valued derivative $\frac32 z^{1/2}$ everywhere else, and that has a limit ($0$) at $z=0$, so we can "define" that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @user8268 While elaboration would be a plus, I think you could post that comment verbatim as an answer.